# Virtual Column Issue with Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, virtual-column

I have an Interface which's created with Oracle Forms. It has a `base table block` in which there's a field (namely `col3`"*has the same name with the table's column that's derived from*").

Form has two other fields `col1` and `col2` as of numeric type, and those fields are also members of the same table having `col3` column mentioned above.

I converted `col3` to a virtual column as the sum of the columns `col1` and `col2` in the table's definition( `col3  number generated always as (nvl(col1,0)+nvl(col2,0)) virtual` )

When I try to commit the changes in the base table it hurls the error message

> **ORA-54013:** *INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns*

I know applying a DML to a virtual column has no sense, but even I changed the `col3` field's

- `Query Only` property from `No` to `Yes`
- `Update Allowed` property from `Yes` to `No`
- `Insert Allowed` property from `Yes` to `No`

I get the same error message. I don't want to write explicit DML statements, since the form has lots of other fields, and they should also be listed in those statements.

Do you have any idea how I can overcome this problem without giving up `base table block` structure ? ( *I'm using the version Fusion Middleware 11g* )

Comment: Not sure if this will affect inserts, but does setting the block property **Update Changed Columns Only** to "Yes" make any difference?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Even converting **Update Only if NULL** to "Yes" doesn't make any difference. Thanks.

Comment: Ok - I thought that would probably be the case. Cheers.

Comment: hi dear Barbaros, is there any possibity to be in touch with you.
Best regards.

Comment: hi dear @RF1991 , there's linked-in address of mine at the profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everything you do with that column is *query*, how about setting it to be a non-database column? It would require writing a `POST-QUERY` trigger, though - otherwise you wouldn't see its value after executing a query.

```
:block.col3 := :block.col1 + :block.col2;
```

Put the same code into `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` triggers on both `:block.col1` and `:block.col2` items, so that you'd calculate the result when inserting/updating values.

Alternatively, create a **procedure** (within the form), put the above code into it, and then call the procedure from those triggers - for a long term, that's probably a better choice as you'd have to maintain code changes only in the procedure.

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot, it seems there's no a direct way to exploit the features of a virtual column through forms as an old technology.

Comment: You're welcome, Barbaros. You didn't specify which Forms version you use - maybe the latest one supports that feature. I can't tell, we're still on 10g.